# Need to find and delete duplicate records in Netezza

Tags: duplicates, netezza

I need a netezza query to delete exact duplicate records and keep only unique records.
with how many ways we can delete duplicates in netezza.

Thanks in advance.
RG

Answer (score 1):

This is probably the *least* sofisticated Solution:

```
Create table X as select distinct * from YOURTABLE
;
```

---- make sure X looks as you expect ----

```
Truncate table YOURTABLE
;
Insert into YOURTABLE select * from X
;
```

You may choose to create the table X as ‘temp’, but the risk of loosing data is potentially higher if you are not 100% sure what you are doing...

Comment: Maybe the least sophisticated approach but CTAS is also probably the best.  I feel a little nervous about the temp table approach with a new user.  I could foresee a situation.m where a new user could accidentally truncate the source table and losing the temp table.

Comment: You are probably right Scott... I feel that the ‘make sure’ is 25% a disclaimer on my side, and disclaimers shouldn’t be necessary amongst friends. I’ll edit the answer.

Comment: Thanks bro for least solution.